# How to pass an additional inventory file (dynamic inventory script) in molecule?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, molecule

In my playbook I use var `group[inventory_group]`. And I need to use my dynamic inventory script. In [the documentation](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) I found:

> Like above, it is possible to pass an additional inventory file (or
> even dynamic inventory script), using the hosts key. Ansible will
> automatically merge this inventory with the one generated by molecule.
> This can be useful if you want to define extra hosts that are not
> managed by Molecule.

But I didn't find any examples.

So, how do I "pass an additional inventory file (or even dynamic inventory script), using the hosts key" ?

Comment: "above" is talking about links and there is a full example right below the paragraph you cited.

Comment: Your var misspells inventory, I didn't know if that is in your code as well so I haven't corrected that

Comment: No. "above"  it's example of static inventory. I need dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could execute the dynamic inventory script in `create` or `prepare` steps in the molecule scenario, and then use the `add_host` module to add the hosts to the in memory inventory?

So something like:

```yaml
- command:
    cmd: /path/to/your_dynamic_inventory_scri.pt
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: dynamic_inventory


- add_host:
    name: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ dynamic_inventory.stdout_lines }}"
```